# How to add value to just certain values in array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have the following code. And I want any part that returns a value 2 to get added a marker so I could later just call them with

```
if(isset($array['Marker'])){do something}
```

The code I am using to sort the array is this one

```
if(in_array(2, array_count_values($array['CustomerID'])) && 0 < $array['status'] < 5) {}
```

While I could do something like this

```
      if(in_array(2, array_count_values($array['CustomerID'])) && 0 < $array['status'] < 5) {
   foreach($array['CustomerID'] as $customerID){
     if($customerID%2 == 0){
     //add to the main array in here?
   }
   }
   }
```

it would take too long since the DB is quit big and it already needs a couple of seconds to load. And I need to do through most of the DB.

Answer (score -1):

[Comment]you might want to look into PHP Arithmetic Operators (%    Modulus)https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp